# Giphy Project issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

The console says unexpected token function on line 5 which is the createButtons() function. I've been trying to fix this for hours and can't figure it out. I'm thinking that the search() and results() functions are also incorrect.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

let topics = ["football", "baseball", "basketball", "golf"],

function createButtons() {
    for (let i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
        let newButton = $("<button>");
        newButton.attr("data-search", topics[i]);
        newButton.addClass("btn");
        newButton.text(topics[i]);
        $("#buttonContainer").append(newButton);
    }
}
function search() {
    let userSearch = $("#search").val();

    if (topics.indexOf(userSearch) < 0 && userSearch.length > 0) {
        topics.push(userSearch);
        let newButton = $("<button>");
        newButton.attr("data-search", userSearch);
        newButton.addClass("btn");
        newButton.text(userSearch);
        $("#buttonContainer").append(newButton);
    }
}

function results() {
    $("#gifContainer").empty();

    let queryURL = "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/trending?api_key=09JboqMeuKdCSPDeYu36R8yKaFL31c28";

    $.ajax({
        url: queryURL,
        method: "GET"
    }).then(function (response) {

        for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            let gif = $("<div>");
            gif.addClass("newGif");
        }
    })
}
    $(document).ready(function () {
    createButtons();

    $("#submit").click(function() {
        search();
        results();
    })
})
})
```

Comment: You only need to change the last comma `,` to a semicolon `;` in the second line of code `let topics ...`

Comment: Wow, I knew it had to be something little like that. Thank you